# reading symbols from application configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I'm reading a password from a config file with my C# application (it's a windows service). I'm using these lines:

```
private NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string password = appSettings["Password"];
```

The config looks like:

```
<add key="Password" value="exam&ple" />
```

The service can't start because the application configuration is incorrect. If I remove the '&', the service works. How could I control this problem?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your values in the app.config like this

```
<add key="Password" value="exam&amp;ple"/>
```